# Limit requests per t in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a REST service in spring boot and I've come across a problem I can't solve. Been googling for hours but most examples seem to bee way too complicated for me because I'm new to Spring Boot.

Let's assume a user can save an object into my database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void saveName (@RequestParam String name){
    personRepository.save(new Person(name));
}
```

Now I have been trying to find a way so an anonymous user can only make a limited amount of entries per minute.

Comment: do you want to do it so a particular ip can make limited amount of requests in a stipulated amount of time? You can use a handlerInterceptor. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-

Comment: This will be invoked before the rest controller is itself invoked. You can override the prehandle method and then based on a condition there as in, if this ip has made too many requests in the last few minutes, return false.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I've been looking for. Will have to check out how this works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use the getRemoteAddr() method on httpServletRequest to get the remote ip address.

Comment: I have managed to intercept the call and get the ip but where could I save it? Do I have to create a service for this?

Comment: That’s ur decision. U could use cache, database, concurrent hash map. Down to u. Depends upon ur requirements.

Comment: I have just implemented a naive approach.

Comment: Let's say I want to limit the amount of requests per IP by one for every 5 seconds. How is it possible to create a component that saves IP addresses and timestamps and deletes them again?

Comment: Just for proof of concept, I will use a in memory concurrent hash map. Key will be ip address, value will be no.of requests. Every request u get , u check has it exceeded one , if it has not , increment the value for that key(ip address) in concurrent hash map and allow it to pass through. If it has, send a response as exceeded limit. 
You can take help of scheduling in spring , to clean the concurrent hash map every 5 seconds.

Comment: This is a very naive implementation. Use it only for Proof Of Concept. , not in production.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Spring Security for this problem. You can check if the user is anonymous through `isAnonymous()` annotation and to limit it you can use a table to capture the attempts. Since you are new to Spring Boot. It's better to brush up on Spring Security as it gives you a fine-grained control over it.
If you do not want spring security, then, the same approach applies, use a table to capture unauthenticated user attempts. Also, there is a default session id, you could make use of this instead of going through the hassle of getting Ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the client is not an authenticated user, it still has its own session, so you can store in the session how many entries he has added. Don't store an interger but a collection of times, so you can remove the old ones if they are older than a minute.